# jquery datepicker inside absolute container

Tags: jquery, datepicker, css-position, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquerydatetimepicker

Am trying to place jquery datepicker input text inside a div that is absolutely positioned. The datepicker calendar is not displayed on clicking the input field, apparently because the calendar div is positioned absolute too. If i change position of parent div to relative, picker is displayed. But i require that the div be positioned absolute. What is the solution to this?

```
<div id="createWizard" style="position:absolute !important">    
    <table height="100%" width="100%" style="height:100%;width:100%;background:transparent;" align="center" valign="center" cellpadding="5">
        <tr height="100%" style="width:100%">
            <td id="wayptsTray">
                <table height="100%" width="100%" valign="top">

                    <tr height="15%" id="StartTimeRow">
                        <td width="100%">
                            <table width="100%" height="100%" valign="middle">
                                <tr height="33.3%">
                                    <td align="left" colspan="2" nowrap>
                                        <span class="wizardHeader" id="routeStartTimeHeader">route time</span>  
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="33.3%">
                                    <td align="left" width="50%" nowrap>
                                        <span class="wizardHeader" id="startDateHeader">date</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="50%" nowrap>
                                        <span class="wizardHeader" id="startTimeHeader">time</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr height="33.3%">
                                    <td align="left" width="50%" nowrap>
                                        <!--div style="position:relative !important;width:100%;height:100%"-->
                                        <input type="text" class="litedark datepicker popupFrmArea datePickerInput datePickerText whitebg" name="startDate"  id="startDate" readonly="readonly"  style="margin-bottom:0px !important;width:85% !important;height:100% !important;"/>
                                        <font color="red" size="2" weight="300" style="width:15% !important;height:100% !important;text-align:left;">*</font>
                                        <!--/div-->
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="left" width="50%" nowrap>
                                        <input type="text" class="litedark popupFrmArea datePickerInput datePickerText whitebg" name="startTime"  id="startTime" readonly="readonly"  style="margin-bottom:0px !important;width:85% !important;height:100% !important"/>
                                        <font color="red" size="2" weight="300" style="width:15% !important;height:100% !important">*</font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr height="65%" id="wayptsRow">
                        <td width="100%">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

date picker code:

```
    var today=new Date();
    var expiryLimit=25;
    var curryear=today.getFullYear();
    $("#startDate.datePickerInput").datepicker({
        minDate:today,
        maxDate:"+"+expiryLimit+"y",
        yearRange:curryear+":"+curryear+expiryLimit,
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true
    });
    $( "#startDate.datePickerInput" ).datepicker( "setDate", today );
```

Comment: What about code example?

Comment: you want theoretical answer, don't do what you are doing and change position to `relative` or post your code and let us have look at it so you may get a solution.

Comment: I have added the code sample. Please check the same. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This may do:

```
<table height="100%" width="100%" style="position: relative; height:100%;width:100%;background:transparent;" align="center" valign="center" cellpadding="5">
```

-- add `position: relative;` to the table style. In this case the date picker will be positioned relative to the table element.

This might be best, as you mostly would expect the date picker to pop up next to the input element that triggers it:

```
<td align="left" width="50%" nowrap>
    <div style="position:relative !important;width:100%;height:100%">
        <input type="text" class="litedark datepicker popupFrmArea datePickerInput datePickerText whitebg" name="startDate"  id="startDate" readonly="readonly"  style="margin-bottom:0px !important;width:85% !important;height:100% !important;"/>
        <font color="red" size="2" weight="300" style="width:15% !important;height:100% !important;text-align:left;">*</font>
    </div>
</td>
```

The main concept is that **an absolutely positioned element use the next ancestor with a relative position as a reference**.

---

As an aside, consider using the `<span>` element in place of the **obsolete** `<font>` (which may not be recognised by some browsers) as follows:

```
<span color="red" size="2" weight="300" style="width:15% !important;height:100% !important;text-align:left;">*</span>
```

Comment: As you can see in my code, i have commented the parent div of datepicker input element. because i tried placing a relative positioned div as parent to the input field in vain. it still doesnt work. the datepicker is not displayed.

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: meanwhile, you called datePicker twice. Is there any reason for you to do so? How about you remove the last call and see how it goes..